# Images dont float right next to contact form css

Tags: html, css

For a school project a need to make a website. I have a contact form page and to the right I want three images. See picture for how it looks now. The images float under the form and not on the right of it. [image] Here is some html and css code:

```css
#contact-img1,
#contact-img2,
#contact-img3 {
  width: 20%;
  height: auto;
  float: right;
}

#contactform {
  width: 70%;
  height: 500px;
  float: left;
}

.shoes {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<fieldset id="contactform">
  <legend>If you have a question you can ask it here:</legend>
  <p> <label for="name">Name:</label> </p>
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <p> <label for="email">Email:</label> </p>
  <input type="text" value="placeholder@gmail.com" name="email">
  <p> <label for="message">Message:</label> </p>
  <input type="text" name="message">
  <p>
    <form action="contact.html">
  </p>
  <input type="submit" value="send question!" />
  </form>
</fieldset>
<section class="shoes">
  <aside class="img-inno1">
    <img id="contact-img1" src="images/inno-img1.webp" alt="first sport image">
  </aside>
  <aside class="img-inno2">
    <img id="contact-img2" src="images/inno-img2.webp" alt="second sport image">
  </aside>
  <aside class="img-inno3">
    <img id="contact-img3" src="images/inno-img3.webp" alt="third sport image">
  </aside>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

Floating an element allows content that **follows** it to bubble up beside it.

It does not cause the floated element to bubble up beside content before it.

To get the form next to the images using floats you would need to either:

- Change the source order
- Float the form instead of the images

---

That said. The point of float is to achieve this sort of effect (as shown in the CSS specification):

[image: floats in action]

Using them to make blocks of content site beside each other is a hack.

We have [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) for that type of layout now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 .shoes {
float:right; 
width:20%;
}
.shoes aside {
 display: inline-block:
}
.shoes img {
max-width: 100%;
}
```